# Group generated by $x , y$ is non-commutative when $x^2 \cdot y^{-3} = I$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**The problem:**
Suppose group $G$ with generators $x$ and $y$ is defined by the relation  $x^2 \cdot y^{-3}  = I$. It is necessary to show that the group is non-commutative.

I failed to solve the problem myself. In the answers I found  that the solution is based on adjoining additional relationships $x^2 = I$ and $(xy)^2=I$ to form a factor group G/K which is $D_3$ and non-commutative. Thus G is also non-commutative.

I can't understand how these additional relationships form $G/K$. And what is $K$ in this case?

**UPD**

I've got a lot of comments and an answer. Actually I've got what I asked. But something is staying unclear for me. Suppose $G$ has no relations only generators $x,y$. Then I add relationships $x^2=I$, $y^3=I$ and $(xy)^2=I$ and get non-communicate $G/K$. In this way I can prove whatever I want. I know that it is silly but I mistake something very important in this topic.

Comment: $K$ the is normal hull of the subgroup generated by $\{x^2,(xy)^2\}$.

Comment: Maybe this simple analogous example will help you. Take G to be generated by $x$ alone with no relations. Then $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. Now add the relation $x^n = I$. You obtain the group $G/H \equiv \mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$, where $H$ is the subgroup generated by $x^n$, i.e. $H \equiv n \mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: When you modulo by a (normal) subgroup, you essentially "equate everything in that subgroup to the identity". It's a form of condensing information.

Comment: There is no need to understand what $K$ is, nor is there any need to figure out what extra relations are needed. All you need to know is that there exist elements $a,b \in D_3$ with $a^2b^{-3}=1$ and $ab \ne ba$. From this, it  It follows from the basic theory of group presentations that there exists a homomorphism $\phi:G \to D_3$ with $\phi(x)=a$, $\phi(y)=b$, and since $\phi(xy) \ne \phi(yx)$, $xy \ne yx$ and hence $G$ is non-commutative.

Comment: Perhaps the original poster doesn't understand that "adding relations" is the "same" (equivalent to) as "taking a quotient", which is also the same as "looking at a homomorphic image". When first looking at groups, people often can't see the forest for the trees-their focus is on the *particular* nature of the example at hand, and not the larger rules of propagation, which comes with experience.

Comment: @DavidWheeler It is hard to explain what I don't understand exactly, but maybe my update can help. Please, have a look at.

Comment: Well, no, you can't prove "whatever you want". But what *is* true, is that *any* group generated by two elements is a quotient group of the free group on two generators. What "allows" this, is the "freeness" of free groups. They're like "groups with no rules" (except the ones you have to have, to be a group), and if we "add rules" we get various other groups.

Comment: @DavidWheeler I see. How can I be sure that I haven't lost or added some property  of the group by adding new rules? In the problem I have only one relation. The other two are main. Maybe I've added non-commutativity with them. Perhaps there are other relationships which allow me to have a commutative factor group.

Comment: That *can* actually happen. For example adding the relation $xyx^{-1}y^{-1} = 1$ would make a group generated by $x$ and $y$ abelian (commutative). However, if your quotient is non-abelian, the "main group" must also be non-abelian, because a quotient of an abelian group is again abelian. So to "finish" the proof properly, you would have to show $S_3 \cong D_3$ is non-abelian, but that isn't too hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending on the comments, or with a method slightly different: define

$$\phi:G\to S_3\;,\;\;\phi x=(12)\;,\;\;\phi y=(123)$$

Observe the unique relation *is kept* under $\;\phi\;$ , since

$$(1)=\phi1=\phi\left(x^2y^{-3}\right)\stackrel ?=\phi\left(x\right)^2\phi\left(y\right)^{-3}=(12)^2(123)^{-3}=(1)(1)=(1)\;\;\color{green}\checkmark$$

and thus we have a well defined homomorphism, and its image is the whole $\;S_3\;$ as we know that $\;S_n=\langle (12),\,\,(12...n)\rangle\;$, and thus we have a non-abelian homomorphic image of $\;G\;$ so $\;G\;$ can't be abelian.

Check/prove that $\;\ker\phi=K\;$ as in your question